# Definition "für" oder "über" einen Terminus - Welche Präposition ist hierbei korrekt/er?

Tags: preposition

Welche Präposition ist/klingt im folgenden Anwendungsszenario korrekter?

1) Die Fachliteratur von Max Mustermann liefert eine Definition

> **über**

den Terminus "transObjects®".

2) Die Fachliteratur von Max Mustermann liefert eine Definition

> **für**

den Terminus "transObjects®".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich würde keine von beiden bevorzugen, sondern den Genitiv nehmen, der sich etwas "gewählter" anhört, einen nicht vor die Wahl der Präposition stellt, und auch noch treffender ist:

> Die Fachliteratur von Max Mustermann liefert eine Definition **des** Terminus "transObjects®".

Wenn die Wahl wirklich auf eine Präposition fallen müsste, würde ich auf keinen Fall "über" wählen. Die Definition des Dudens von "über" für diesen Kontext sieht so aus:

> bezeichnet Inhalt oder Thema einer mündlichen oder schriftlichen Äußerung

Man schreibt ein Buch oder ein Aufsatz über ein Ding, aber keine Definition.

Comment: Danke für den tollen Vorschlag!

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde definitiv die zweite Variante bevorzugen, also "für".
Leider kann ich nicht genau erklären, wieso ich diese Variante bevorzugen würde, meine Empfehlung basiert ausschlichlich auf meinem Sprachgefühl.

Comment: Diese Variante habe ich tatsächlich auch aktuell in Verwendung :)